# Does kafka sink connector inserts record if the transformation returns NULL?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka sink connector (elasticsearch), and I'm writing a custom SMT. I'm wondering what would happen if the SMT returns a `NULL` record. What the connector would do ? Is it going to insert something `NULL` in my elasticsearch index ? Or is it going to not insert at all ?

Comment: this SO answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60540286/4039431

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested about the kafka connector behaviour rather than elastisearch

Comment: but you said `insert something NULL in my elasticsearch index ? Or is it going to not insert at all ?` and my answer will help you understand what ES will store based on what your connector is sending

Comment: Yes I meant, does the kafka connector will skip this record ? Or is it still going to insert `NULL` to ES ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control how it's handled using the `behavior.on.null.values` config option.

- `ignore` - the message is ignored
- `delete` - the Elasticsearch record with matching key is deleted
- `fail` - the connector will stop.

Ref: [doc page](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html#data-conversion)